# How to make custom blocks print unsanitized markup

Tags: 8, blocks

Goal: I like to create a block to display phone no and a link as shown below:

[image]

Structure > Block layout > custom block > Add custom block, added this:

[image]

When I go to my site, I see this:

[image]

How can I create a block based on my above goal?

---

**Update 1**

Full HTML shows no CKEditor

[image]

FULL HTML > Configure shows this:

[image]

Block:

[image]

My page still shows html code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TWO solutions:

1.-in text formats, disable WYSYWIG in full-html format, you are looking HTML tags because of this.

2.-write your code in plain-text format, select 'plain-text' write code, when done, do choose full-html and save your block.

in other words, do not write code inside WYSYWIG.

Comment: How do I disable WYSYWIG ? Drop down list displays Basic, restricted, and FULL html. I do not see plain text option.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9RD6PTxe9U, i named WYSYWIG, is named CKeditor, just disable CKeditor in full-html

Comment: Video talked about how to configure plan text. I selected CKeditor. I dragged horizontal rule to active tools. Drop down list does not show plaintext option after clearing cache. Video did not address how to disable WYSYWIG. I am stuck.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/DpH8RuB, here are configuring basic-html CKedior, you need to configure FULL-HTML CKeditor, and as you can see in 1:27 min in video there is a dropdown to choose wether or not use CKeditor, do choose NONE in full-html, done.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/tYd8QIm

Comment: uncheck this checkbox, display any HTML as plain-text https://imgur.com/a/7CEJCiL